# Escaping Variables in View?

Tags: node.js, xss, sql-injection

I'm wondering how to escape variables in my view, in my Node.js project.

For example #{name} in my .jade view file seems vulnerable to SQL Injection or XSS. Is there a standard way to resolve this? I know in ruby I would do <%= h name %> for example...

Comment: IIRC, Jade escapes by default.

Comment: Yes jade escapes by default, use !{} if you don't want escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually want #{} for some reason? escape it!

p \#{something}
now we have <p>#{something}</p>

We can also utilize the unescaped variant !{html}, so the following will result in a literal script tag:

- var html = "<script></script>"
| !{html}
```

from https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

Comment: I see. So is there any difference between (message is a variable):
p= message
p #{message}

Comment: The variables message and #{message} are the same, it just depends on where/how you use them.  The following article helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709560/in-jade-why-can-i-sometimes-use-variables-as-is-and-on-other-times-have-to-encl